# Badge not awarded even though it shows completion?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, user-interface

I recently checked into my profile and found that the "Curious Badge" showed progress completion and it showed 9/5 days, which was kind of peculiar.

I don't know if I had actually completed the badge progress or if it was a bug or if I had not interpreted it correctly.

Please clarify about this issue.

Comment: *cough* positive question record *cough*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need a so-called [positive question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/295232) for the Curious badge and related badges.

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is
>
> ```
> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5`
> ```
>
> Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!

You must have quite a few deleted questions, since [those which *are* visible](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/93148/vamsi-krishna?tab=questions) are quite positive on average. The ones deleted within the last 60 days are still visible in your profile, via the 'deleted recent questions' option.